# Applying to my first reference and using him as referee

Tags: phd, application, reference-request

The question may be ill structured, because I do not know how to put it more concisely. I am applying for a research position (officially, using the application portal) to my best reference.

Is it okay to use my best reference's email as my primary reference for the position?

Just to make things clearer, Mr.A is my best reference. I really loved working under Mr.A and but before I could join him for further studies, he went to a different school. He, however did become my best reference and helped me with many references. Now that Mr.A has open position, I want to apply under him. However, because he is my best reference, is it okay to give his email as my first reference?

Comment: It feels a bit pointless to use A as a reference when applying for a position with A.

Comment: @xLeitix why would that be? He is a reference from a point when he was at a different university.

Comment: So what? I really have a hard time seeing what you are trying to achieve. A knows you. There is literally no point in A writing a letter *to himself* certifying how qualified you are. The point of reference letters is to get *other people's opinion*, no?

Comment: @xLeitix Ah! Loud and clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, Mr A. moved to another institution and you want to apply to a position at that institution under the same Mr A.

Your best course of action would be to contact Mr A. directly and tell him that you would love to apply for that position and ask him whether it is ok for you to include him as a reference. This would then of course be just a formality, as Mr A wouldn't write a reference to himself, but it would serve to fill out the field and to implicitly constitute a recommendation.

This is important as to counter any eventual conflict of interest. If Mr A can't be your reference, perhaps he can point you to others (this part of your question is a bit confusing).

There are institutions where students apply directly to the professors, if that is applicable here, Mr A could be more inclined to accept you.

Comment: I disagree slightly: OP should of course contact A, but shouldn't put his email in the reference box. There's no point. OP should put someone else's email there.

Comment: @astronat I feel the same. I ran this argument in my head and it does not make any sense putting Mr.A's email.

Comment: @astronat this was intended solely to cover the formality angle. if A knows OP and A handles the admission, i.e. contacts the references, then OPs reference is superfluous as A has already all the information. if that is the case, it can only be that the form may not be left blank, so a reference has to be specified.